# Convert this timestamp to a shorter more readable format?

Tags: date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a timestamp that looks like this:

```
2018-02-12T04:30:31.825636
```

But I cannot figure out what type of timestamp that is, all the converters I've tried say it's invalid.

Have you come across this format timestamp? how did you deal with it? 
I want to avoid splicing the string or modifying the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an ISO 8601-formatted timestamp. It's an international standard; almost every language should be able to parse it using a library.

Comment: Awesome!  Now I just need to figure out how to convert from SIO string to what I need.  :) TY!!